# jQuery div shows div intermitently

Tags: jquery, html

I need a bit of help again... I have this code:

```
<div id="lyrics">
    <div id="lyricsClose"></div>
    <div id="ajax-content"></div>
</div>
```

id **lyrics and lyricsClose** are hidden. I basically want an overlayed div that shows lyrics, with a close button on the top, right. So, with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('[id^=showContent]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent link acting as link
    $("body").append("<div id='lyricsOverlay'></div>");
    $("#lyricsOverlay").height($(document).height());
    $('#lyrics').css("display", "table"); 
        $('#lyrics').hover(function() {
            $('#lyricsClose').toggle();
        });         
        $('#lyrics').mouseleave(function() {
            $('#lyricsClose').css("display", "none");
        });
    $('#lyrics').show(); // Show content layer
    $('#lyricsOverlay').click(function() { 
            $('#lyrics').hide();
            $('#lyricsOverlay').remove();
        });     
    $('#lyricsClose').click(function() { 
            $('#lyrics').hide();
            $('#lyricsOverlay').remove();
        });
    });
})
```

When clicking:

Works fine, BUT, only sometimes. First time clicking works perfectly, second time lyricsClose div dissapears and does not show. Third time OK again, fourth KO, ...

I suppose something is wrong in my jQuery code... Can't se what it is...

Thanks!

Comment: Need the code to check this out.. Do you have a fiddle ??

Comment: I try to make one, never used it, give some mins hehe

Comment: @sushanthreddy jsfiddle! Sry, It was difficutl hehe: http://jsfiddle.net/yajGy/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constantly re-binding the `hover` and `mouseleave` events.
As the `hover` event calls `toggle` it calls it for every binding, couter-acting the previous execution.

- Second time it shows, hides
- Third time it shows, hides, shows
- Fourth time it shows, hides, shows, hides

Unbinding the events before re-binding should fix it.

```
$('#lyrics').unbind("hover").hover(function() {
    $('#lyricsClose').toggle();
});

$('#lyrics').unbind("mouseleave").mouseleave(function() {
    $('#lyricsClose').css("display", "none");
});
```

Also, as you already set the display value of `#lyrics` `.show()` is redundant.

```
/// not needed because as soon as you set above display to table it becomes visible
$('#lyrics').show(); // Show content layer
```

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FranWahl/mdhY8/) - Unbind before re-binding

Comment: @qalbiol: No worries, you are more than welcome. Event bindings are not the most transparent.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery >= 1.7, use the following delegation:

```
$('[id^=showContent]').click(function(e) {
```

change to:

```
$(document).on("click","[id^=showContent]",function(e){
```

... this doesn't answer the question, but given the information here, should solve the problem. Instead of $(document), I usually prefer an inner container but one which contains the elements triggering the click event.

Comment: Why do you think `$('[id^=showContent]')` is dynamic? The only dynamic element I saw was `$("body").append("<div id='lyricsOverlay'></div>");` and that has no events attached. I would assume that if dynamic bindings were the issue that it would not work the first time but the second time instead, or similar.

Comment: showContent divs are created dinamically with PHP like showContent.$i, outputting: showContent0, showContent1...

Comment: @qalbiol: Your elements already existed on the page at the time you were attaching the events, otherwise the events would not have executed in the first place.

Comment: Sry, I really don't understand what your are trying to tell me. :) Problem is solved with the accepted answer.